# Firebase multiple range query work around

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, angularfire2

I have the following query to return a list of items based on their required category and that the created at date is more than or equal to the value i provide.

```
return this.firestore.col$('Items', ref =>
  ref.where(required.programming, '>', 0)
    .where('name', '==', itemName)
    .where('createdAt', '>=', this.mostRecentDate)
    .orderBy("createdAt", "asc").limit(50))
   )
```

I have had to structure my data as an object of keys due to the fact firebase doesn't query fields of arrays. The work around provided by firebase is to provide a structure where each category is the key in a map and the values are unix timestamps (so as they can be indexed).

The problem now is that Firebase cannot handle multiple range comparisons on different fields.

```
you can only perform range comparisons (<, <=, >, >=) on a single field:
```

What would be a good work around for this problem?

Comment: Did you try what results you get if you remove `.orderBy("createdAt", "asc")`? I suspect the results *might* already be sorted, since  the database server needs to sort on `createdAt` anyway to filter on it.

Comment: It still won't work as firebase only allows range comparisons on one field per query

Answer (score 1):

You're trying to filter on a range in `required.programming` and a range in `"createdAt"`. That won't work, as Firestore tells you.

To be able to maintain its performance guarantees, Firestore must be able to find your results in a single range in an index. That is not possible if you try to filter on two unrelated fields like you are doing.

There is no simple workaround for this, otherwise it likely would've been implemented in the database itself already.

Comment: Yes. My application looks for results that have certain tags, such a programming or sports etc. These cannot go in . an array as firebase cannot deal with it and so as per the documentation I put them within an object with UNIX timestamps as their values, so as they could be indexed.